# Brasilia Summer Time transition at 2037-10-18

Tags: java, date, datetime

```java
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("BET"));
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);

SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzzz");

Date d0 = sdf1.parse("2037-10-17 23:00:00.000");
Date d1 = sdf1.parse("2037-10-17 23:00:00.001");
Date d2 = sdf1.parse("2037-10-17 23:59:59.999");
Date d3 = sdf1.parse("2037-10-18 00:00:00.000");
Date d4 = sdf1.parse("2037-10-18 00:00:00.001");
Date d5 = sdf1.parse("2037-10-18 00:59:59.999");
Date d6 = sdf1.parse("2037-10-18 01:00:00.000");
Date d7 = sdf1.parse("2037-10-18 01:00:00.001");
Date d8 = sdf1.parse("2037-10-18 01:59:59.999");
Date d9 = sdf1.parse("2037-10-18 02:00:00.000");

System.out.println(sdf2.format(d0) + "(" + d0.getTime() + "), dst: " + TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(d0) + ", offset: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(d0.getTime()));
System.out.println(sdf2.format(d1) + "(" + d1.getTime() + "), dst: " + TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(d1) + ", offset: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(d1.getTime()));
System.out.println(sdf2.format(d2) + "(" + d2.getTime() + "), dst: " + TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(d2) + ", offset: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(d2.getTime()));
System.out.println(sdf2.format(d3) + "(" + d3.getTime() + "), dst: " + TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(d3) + ", offset: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(d3.getTime()));
System.out.println(sdf2.format(d4) + "(" + d4.getTime() + "), dst: " + TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(d4) + ", offset: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(d4.getTime()));
System.out.println(sdf2.format(d5) + "(" + d5.getTime() + "), dst: " + TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(d5) + ", offset: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(d5.getTime()));
System.out.println(sdf2.format(d6) + "(" + d6.getTime() + "), dst: " + TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(d6) + ", offset: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(d6.getTime()));
System.out.println(sdf2.format(d7) + "(" + d7.getTime() + "), dst: " + TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(d7) + ", offset: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(d7.getTime()));
System.out.println(sdf2.format(d8) + "(" + d8.getTime() + "), dst: " + TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(d8) + ", offset: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(d8.getTime()));
System.out.println(sdf2.format(d9) + "(" + d9.getTime() + "), dst: " + TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(d9) + ", offset: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(d9.getTime()));
```

the out put

```
2037-10-17 23:00:00.000 Brasilia Time(2139444000000), dst: false, offset: -10800000
2037-10-17 23:00:00.001 Brasilia Time(2139444000001), dst: false, offset: -10800000
2037-10-17 23:59:59.999 Brasilia Time(2139447599999), dst: false, offset: -10800000
2037-10-18 01:00:00.000 Brasilia Summer Time(2139447600000), dst: true, offset: -7200000
2037-10-18 00:00:00.001 Brasilia Time(2139447600001), dst: true, offset: -10800000
2037-10-18 00:59:59.999 Brasilia Time(2139451199999), dst: true, offset: -10800000
2037-10-18 01:00:00.000 Brasilia Summer Time(2139447600000), dst: true, offset: -7200000
2037-10-18 00:00:00.001 Brasilia Time(2139447600001), dst: true, offset: -10800000
2037-10-18 00:59:59.999 Brasilia Time(2139451199999), dst: true, offset: -10800000
2037-10-18 02:00:00.000 Brasilia Summer Time(2139451200000), dst: true, offset: -7200000
```

This code print out the the date times around "2037-10-18 00:00:000 Brasilia Time", the result shows out that "2037-10-18 00:00:000 Brasilia Time" should be "2037-10-18 01:00:00.000 Brasilia Summer Time" that means Brasilia entered the summer time in that moment.

My question is why between "2037-10-18 00:00:00.001 Brasilia Time" and "2037-10-18 00:59:59.999 Brasilia Time" the time zone offset still using standard time offset. Is this a bug of JDK time zone data or this time zone actually works this way.

My code using offset to decide whether or not there is a dst transition between two dates. Obviously "2037-10-18 01:00:00.000 Brasilia Summer Time" and "2037-10-18 00:59:59.999 Brasilia Time" those two dates does not work here.

I can change to use "TimeZone.getDefault().inDaylightTime(Date date)" to decide if there is a transition, but I still want to know if it's a bug of JDK.

Comment: If there is a bug it's probably in the parser since `d3` and `d6` (as well as `d4/7` and  `d5/8`) are parsed to the same long value.

Comment: What Java version and Olson TZDB version?

Comment: It may be a bug - the java.time API seems to give [the correct results](http://ideone.com/XHmdwY).

Comment: Seems like a bug.  Your test date is close enough to the end-of-time that it might be an untested edge condition bug.  "google search 2038 unix bug" for details about the end-of-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to step through the code with a debugger and it seems to be a problem with the timezone and the switch itself: BRT to BRST switches from 00:00:00 to 01:00:00 at midnight, meaning that hour in between actually doesn't exist.

From my debugging the problem seems to be in `GregorianCalendar#computeTime()` especially in the following line:

```
millis -= zoneOffsets[0] + zoneOffsets[1];
```

Before that line `millis` is the time since epoch which has been calculated from the parsed date and which is different for `00:00:00` (213946800000) and `01:00:00` (2139440400000). In both cases `zoneOffsets[0]` is -10800000 which is the raw offset to UTC.

The difference is in `zoneOffsets[1]`: for `00:00:00` it is 0 but for `01:00:00` is is 3600000, i.e. 1 hour. The reason for this seems to be an internal call to `inDaylightTime( new Date(millis) )` which returns false for `00:00:00` (pre-dst) but true for `01:00:00` (which is the first hour of dst). Hence the final time will be the same since you always add 10800000 millis but subtract 3600000 millis from the higher value which is higher by 3600000 millis :)

In the end you get a `Date` with the same milli time.

When formatting the date again it seems like the formatter will check the milli time against the timezone and every time that would correspond to `00:00:00,000 - 59:59:59,999`, i.e. which could be in both time zones will be assumed to have a `dstOffset` of 0 instead of 3600000 and hence different time zones are printed.

**Edit**: when comparing `01:00:00.000` and `01:00:00.001` it seems as if there might be a bug in `ZoneInfo.getOffsets(time, offsets, type)` which returns a dst offset of 360000 for the former and 0 for the latter while when filling the fields of the calendar inside the formatter both will assume dst.

**Edit 2:** When changing the parser format to accept timezone shortcuts you can observe the same behavior, i.e. `00:00:00.000 BRT` and `01:00:00.000 BRST` are parsed to 2139447600000 and formatted again to `01:00:00.000 BRST` while `00:00:00.001 BRT` and `01:00:00.001 BRST` are parsed to 2139447600001 and formatted to `00:00:00.001 BRT` - which in itself is correct.